# After migrate .Net framework from 4.6.2 to 4.7.2, Azure Cloud Services is not working

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-cloud-services, .net-4.7.2

After I migrated .Net framework version from 4.6.2 to 4.7.2, there was no problem with I run locally. However, when I published to Azure Cloud Services, there should be something wrong so the service bus message moved to DeadLetter Queue. What's wrong is it as I chose osFamily to 6 (Windows Server 2019) already?

If I chose back Windows Server 2016, below error was out during starting the service:

> Unhandled Exception: Method not found: ‘Void Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClient..ctor(AuthenticationCallback, System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler[])‘. at Topo.SettingsContext.GetKeyVaultClient(ClientAssertionCertificate assertionCert) at ...

After that, I also tried below method to install .Net framework in WorkerRole manually but still failed:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-startup-tasks-common

Answer (score 1):

The Net Framwork 4.7.2 is not installed by default on a cloud service.

You can follow this article to install it:

- [Install .NET on Azure Cloud Services roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-dotnet-install-dotnet)

Basically you will need to:

1. Include the Net installer in your project.
2. Add a startup task to run the installer as part of the deployment.

Comment: I also followed the link before but stilled fail. May you guide me more do support this? Thanks.

Comment: What do yu mean failed? What is the error you've got ?

Comment: It worked perfect in my local but not Azure Cloud Services. Since this handled message from ServiceBus and I could see the message went to DeadLetter Queue (if ran in local, it could be completed).

Comment: There is no error in Cloud Services. (or can you advise how to see Application Exception Log in Azure Portal?)